# Windows 7 Cmd requires file extensions. E.g. "ping 127.0.0.1" doesn't work, but "ping.exe 127.0.0.1" does

Tags: windows, path, cmd, exe

I tried this with `ping`, `xcopy` and other files in my path like a helloWorld.bat or git.exe. Every command works as long as I append it's file extension, but whenever I omit the extension I get a "command is not recognized" error. This is not a big problem now, but it's still kinda annoying.

Does anyone have an idea where this problem originates from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess the Pathext system environment variable has been deleted.
A minimum typical entry is:

`.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD`

A longer entry with more scripting extensions:

`.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH`

So, check if PATHEXT exists, if not add it.
Here's some instructions on setting environment variables. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Thank you! This got me into the right direction. The PATHEXT system environment variable does exist, but so does the PATHEXT user environment variable and it seems like the user variable overwrote the system variable. 

There are user and system entries for the PATH variable, too, but those don't overwrite each other...